# Listen to Post action

Tags: posts, plugin-development, metabox, editor

I am writing a plugin that adds a custom metabox to the post page. I would like to trigger an event when the user navigates away from the *edit post* page or when a user stops editing a specific post. Is there a way to listen to events on the post page?

Comment: What exactly is `stops editing`...?

Comment: After I have saved (published or abandoned) my post and navigated away to a different post, or closed wordpress all together

Comment: Interesting question. I'm coming up empty. I first thought about using javascript and `onbeforeunload`, but the post editing page already uses that. Then I thought that maybe you could hook into whatever process releases the editing lock, but I actually couldn't find it. If anyone has more time to look into this, I think that's probably the best route.

Answer (score 4):

This is more of a JavaScript the A WordPress Question but anyway, You can use the JavaScript `onbeforeunload` event something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    old = window.onbeforeunload;
    window.onbeforeunload = MyOnExit;
    function MyOnExit(){
        //do your stuff here
        return old();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I think you need "return old();" as a non-null return value triggers the prompt.